# How to view a NTFS filename in HEX view

Tags: ntfs, filenames, hexadecimal

Basically an ill behaved software in my Windows PC is spoiling filenames with illegal characters.
To help the developer to debug this issue, I am looking for a solution to dump the offending filename in HEX view.
Windows 8 NTFS file system

Comment: As it stands it is quite difficult to understand exactly what it is you are asking.  Perhaps try giving an example of what you wish to do for greater clarity

Comment: Edit my question

Comment: Is it the file or the filename you want to view in HEX?

Comment: Yes Toby, I need a tool that can easily show the filename in hex view. Probabily it takes a tool that may read the MFT?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have discovered that [DiskExplorer](http://www.runtime.org/diskexplorer.htm) by Runtime software will show MFT entries in HEX view. Probably other tools will allow this, however my search ends here!
Thanks everyone!
Eventually other users may post here other tools!

Answer (score -1):

MAny text editors will view files in hex view.

- Editpadpro
- Textedit

Probably notepad++ (which is free).

Comment: -1 The OP wants to look at the filename.

Comment: Exactly I do use Notepad++ and HXD, but none of them will allow viewing the filename in hexview